# Error: You must return a Promise in your transaction()-callback. at transaction.begin.then

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, promise, es6-promise

This is my code snippet:

```
await firestore.runTransaction(t => {
        t.get(docRef)
            .then(docRef => {
                logger.info("entering transaction");
                if (!docRef.exists) {
                    t.create(docRef, new Data);
                    return Promise.resolve();
                } else {        
                    t.update(docRef, {aField: updateData});
                    return Promise.resolve();
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return Promise.reject(error);
            });
    })
```

This gives me the following error:

> Error: You must return a Promise in your transaction()-callback. at transaction.begin.then (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:496:32) at

It's my first time using firestore transaction syntax, and I know fairly about nodejs promise concepts and syntax. I mimiced the firestore transaction example [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#runTransaction) and wrote the above snippet.

After the error, I tried to change `Promise.resolve()` to `Promise.resolve(0)`, but in vain.

I also tried to remove `await` and instead use `.then`, but it still gives me the same error.

Please shed some lights on it. Appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but if anyone else is here because they're using Bluebird promises instead of native promises, the firebase code does a check `promise instanceof Promise` and Bluebird promises will fail that check. I had to wrap mine with a native promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to basically `return` the Promise. Also, if `t.create` and `t.update` returns a promise as well, you can just return that. Don't do `return Promise.resolve()`, Which is wrong because it will resolve **BEFORE** actually inserting or creating.

Assuming everything works fine you need to do:

```
await firestore.runTransaction(t => {
  return t.get(docRef)
    .then(docRef => {
      logger.info("entering transaction");
      if (!docRef.exists) {
        return t.create(docRef, new Data);
      } else {
        return t.update(docRef, { aField: updateData });
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
})
```

Comment: Please see the example in Google doc. `t.create` and `t.update` returns another transaction for chaining purpose, not a promise.


I took your hint that `return Promise.resolve()` does not work and replace it with just `Promise.resolve()`. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Looking back the example, I realized i missed `return` in `return t.get()` but the error was in no way obvious to point out my mistake..

Comment: that's literally what i said in the first line of my answer.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I thought your focus are in these words "Don't do return Promise.resolve(), Which is wrong because it will resolve BEFORE actually inserting or creating.", which `return Promis.resolve()` actually works.
But ok, I will select your answer if you modify that line.